# Sum a record when duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've searched for an answer to this all over but couldn't find what i'm really looking for! so i had to ask here..

i don't know how to explain this but here is a table :

```
  Date          BL          Client  Design      Ref1    Ref2    Ref3    Qte
  14/01/2013    13011401    A       VT          VT1     JAUNE   XL      3
  14/01/2013    13011402    B       VT          VT2     GRIS    L       30
  16/01/2013    13011601    D       VT          VT1     GRIS    L       10
  16/01/2013    13011602    C       VT          VT2     GRIS    L       32
  19/01/2013    13011903    F       VT          VT2     JAUNE   L       15
```

i'm looking for a result that could look like the following:

```
  Date          BL          Client  Design      Ref1    Ref2    Ref3    Qte
  14/01/2013    13011401    A       VT          VT1     JAUNE   XL      3
  14/01/2013    13011402    B       VT          VT2     GRIS    L       62
  16/01/2013    13011601    D       VT          VT1     GRIS    L       10
  19/01/2013    13011903    F       VT          VT2     JAUNE   L       15
```

edit: sum **Qte** if there is a duplicate (**Design,Ref1, Ref2, Ref3**)

don't know if this is possible but i would appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you please explain duplicate on basis of what ?

Comment: What I understand from your table is, it is not in normalize form. Try creating two tables, store A,VT,VT1,JAUNE in one table with p_id as primary key. In other table, store quantity,date, integer_id, foreign_key. Then simply you need group by on foreign key and aggregated function on quantity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table : mytable

  col1          col2       Col3     col4    col5    col7    col8    col9
  14/01/2013    13011401    A       VT      VT1     JAUNE   XL      3
  14/01/2013    13011402    B       VT      VT2     GRIS    L       30
  16/01/2013    13011601    D       VT      VT1     GRIS    L       10
  16/01/2013    13011602    C       VT      VT2     GRIS    L       32
  19/01/2013    13011903    F       VT      VT2     JAUNE   L       15
```

What I understood is that You want duplicate on the basis of `col4,col5,col7,col8` for this you can do like

```
SELECT col1,col2,Col3,col4,col5,col7,col8,SUM(col9)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY col4,col5,col7,col8;
```

In this group by will always return first row for other fields

Comment: sorry i've one more question, what if we have two tables and wan't to sub the sum result of the first one from the second one?!

Comment: I am not getting your question clearly , You can post another question so that everybody can help you.

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for something like

```
SELECT *, SUM(field) FROM table
GROUP BY field1, field2
```

where field is the column that you want to sum and field1 and field2 are the columns you want to group

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT *, 
       Sum(field_name) 
FROM   tablename 
GROUP  BY column_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, SUM(field) FROM table GROUP BY field
```

Apply the aggregare function i.e SUM on the field whose sum is required to you and then Group By the same.....

Comment: formatting answer is a good idea...improves readability...welcome to SO mate :)