# add up the result of the sum of two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

i don't if the title is good but anyway, i was wondering if we can add the sum of a table after summing duplicates with another table just like the following example:

Table A:

```
  Date          BL          Client  Design      Ref1    Ref2    Ref3    Qte
  14/01/2013    13011401    A       VT          VT1     JAUNE   XL      3
  14/01/2013    13011402    B       VT          VT2     GRIS    L       62
  16/01/2013    13011601    D       VT          VT1     GRIS    L       10
  19/01/2013    13011903    F       VT          VT2     JAUNE   L       15
```

Table B:

```
  Date          BL          Client  Design      Ref1    Ref2    Ref3    Qte
  14/01/2013    13011401    A       VT          VT1     JAUNE   XL      3
  14/01/2013    13011402    B       VT          VT2     GRIS    L       100
  16/01/2013    13011601    D       VT          VT1     GRIS    L       10
  19/01/2013    13011903    F       VT          VT2     JAUNE   L       15
```

Result:

```
  Date          BL          Client  Design      Ref1    Ref2    Ref3    Qte
  14/01/2013    13011401    A       VT          VT1     JAUNE   XL      6
  14/01/2013    13011402    B       VT          VT2     GRIS    L       162
  16/01/2013    13011601    D       VT          VT1     GRIS    L       20
  19/01/2013    13011903    F       VT          VT2     JAUNE   L       30
```

The condition is that (**Client, Design, Ref1, Ref2, Ref3**) should be the same in the two tables!

Comment: this is duplicate question

Comment: How is that you have added only the 2nd row column and not others as all the columns have same value??

Comment: You don't think Qte is Wrong if (Client, Design, Ref1, Ref2, Ref3) should be the same in the two tables

Comment: @enigmaticus would you like to link me the other question!

Comment: Link to previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22010695/sum-a-record-when-duplicate/22010903?noredirect=1#comment33363573_22010903

Comment: @Gone ouh yes sorry also the other ones!

Comment: @AbdulManaf i don't quite follow what you mean by wrong?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `JOINS`

```
SELECT 
    TableA.Date,
    TableA.BL,
    TableA.Client,
    TableA.Design,
    TableA.Ref1,
    TableA.Ref2,
    TableA.Ref3,
    TableA.Qte + TableB.Qte As Qte
FROM
    TableA
        JOIN
    TableB ON TableA.Client = TableB.Client
        AND TableA.Design = TableB.Design
        AND TableA.Ref1 = TableB.Ref1
        AND TableA.Ref2 = TableB.Ref2
        AND TableA.Ref3 = TableB.Ref3;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want

```
select t.Date,t.BL,t.Client,t.Design,t.Ref1,t.Ref2,t.Ref3, t.Qte+t1.Qte as qte
from table1 t inner join table2 t1
on t.client=t1.client and
   t.design=t1.design and
   t.ref1=t1.ref1 and
   t.ref2=t1.ref2 and
   t.ref3=t1.ref3;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach.  It can be extended to handle more than two tables.

```
SELECT   Date, BL, Client, Design, Ref1, Ref2, Ref3, SUM(Qte) Qte
FROM (
  SELECT Date, BL, Client, Design, Ref1, Ref2, Ref3, Qte FROM TableA
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Date, BL, Client, Design, Ref1, Ref2, Ref3, Qte FROM TableB
) t
GROUP BY Date, BL, Client, Design, Ref1, Ref2, Ref3, Qte
```